# How to store a time duration value to be read in decimal, hh:mm, etc

Tags: database, performance, math, time

I create a pilot logbook software application and pilots log flight time in various formats.  In the US pilots log flight time typically in tenths, i.e. 90 minutes of flying would be logged as 1.5.  International/European pilots typically log time in HH:MM so the 90 minutes would be logged as 1:30.  Some may also want other formats such as 1 + 30.

I need a universal way of storing this value in SQL Server such that it can be converted to the display format as shown above.  I'd hate to have to have two columns for every field, one is decimal time, the other is total minutes.  Or I could convert somehow the decimal time into a total minutes representation and store it as an INT.

We've also discussed storing TICKS.  The problem come into aggregating the values later in reports, pivot table systems such as DevExpress's XtraPivotGrid, etc.  And even more of a concern is how will this data be handled on mobile devices such as the logbook apps on iPhone, Android, etc. using SQLite.  In the past we had issues with Palm OS and the size of the number (integer) and overflow problems.  When you add up TICKS from 30 years of a pilots flying you could end up with a huge number.  Doing averages, etc....

For pilots that track flight time in decimal we use time scales such as 27-33 minutes is a .5 so if you fly for 32 minutes, you log a 0.5 or 1 hour and 33 minutes you would log it as a 1.5, so we need to apply the time scale when converting the stored value to the display value.  For European it would be 1:33 for the last case that was logged as a 1.5 in the US.

How do you suggest we store a pilot's flight time in the database so it can be converted to tenths, hundredths, or HH:MM presentation?  Also consider aggregates, mobile apps, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: *Never* store cultural dependent data in a dbase.  The logical choice here is a number column, storing minutes or seconds.  Using 100 nanosecond ticks is overkill.  The actual display of the data is always the responsibility of the GUI app.  Not just whatever unit is appropriate in the location but also the string format.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of `TIME` (or `DATETIME` as you wish) native to your database's variant of SQL.  Transform to/from the external representations as required on output/input.

Comment: It's not a TIME or DATE/TIME value, it's an accumulation of hours and minutes for the task, i.e. the flight.  So it's not 8:00 AM per se, it's 360 minutes for the duration of the flight.  We either present this as 6:00 or 6.0.

Comment: The documentation for MySQL indicates that TIME can take values in the range  '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59' which seems suitable for your requirement.  Which SQL dialect are you using ?